# How facebook auth by js?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need a apps where user can login & after login some info will shown. But I have faces many problems several times. Please help me to correct this. SOmetime shows FB not recognized, sometimes shows GET file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND .

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Facebook </title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href = "#" onClick = "FB.getLoginStatus()">Login</a>
<script>
  // Additional JS functions here
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxx', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional init code here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // connected
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // not_authorized
        login();
      } else {
        // not_logged_in
       login();
      }
    });
  };

  function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        testAPI() ;
      } else {
        // cancelled
      }
    });
  }

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";` Add `http:` in front of `//` when you are testing it with the `file://` scheme.

Comment: I have faces : Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.  I think this error occured for application setting.  Need web url for this. I am just working test project on one html file. So what will be my local URL ?

Comment: I  am facing problem for redirect url of facebook apps. I cant understand what will be my redirect url ? I have just a html file locally. My path : D:\\facebook.index.html . so what will be my redirect url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add http: in front of //. I think this is necessary.